# Is MergeSort or QuickSort more efficient with arrays between 100 and 1000 elements?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sorting, mergesort

I am implementing a sorting algorithm in python, and want to know whether MergeSort or QuickSort would have a better average case.

Are there any programs that can compare the efficiency of these sorting algorithms given an array with n elements?

Which algorithm is generally faster (not a specific case)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html - use time it in order to find time of execution & you can compare efficiency...Logically quick sort idealy faster than Merge sort...But, Merge sort is more secure, quick sort is vulnarable to DdOS. But only issue is merge sort is space complexity... To be honest use `buil-in` sort which will be more than enough in this case..

Comment: It depends on your data.  But, independent of your data, you will have a hard time beating the built-in `sort` function.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use the built in sort in this case, despite its efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

QuickSort has worst case O(n²) and mergeSort O(n log n). So if you know nothing about your specific input, in worst case mergeSort is faster.

If your input has charactaristicas that avoid this worst case for QuickSort, it might be quicker on average.

I recommend simply profile both algorithms with a big enough sample of your input-data.